# CSS - Indent list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is there a way to indent each list-item using CSS?

So a normal list:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Displays like so:

```
One
  Two
    Three
      Four
```

Comment: `nth-child` selector with progressive values should help but that sounds like too bulky an approach. Sass/Less loops will help minimize the code that needs to be written but the end CSS (compiled) will still be bulky.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you can use `:before` pseudo-element with transparent border.
You can variate indent of list item by changing a width of pseudo-element.
Along with that you can change list marker if set `list-style: none;` and set `color` of `content`

#### EDIT:

removed `display: block` and `color: transparent` and used space character `\00a0` as a content.

```css
li:before {
    float: left;
    content: "\00a0";
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

The following one is little more complex with changed list marker (removed `display: block` as advised by @dippas, but `border-top` instead `border` didn't work for some reason)

```css
ul {
   list-style: none;
   counter-reset: cnt;
}

li:before {
   float: left;
   counter-increment: cnt;
   content: counter(cnt)" \25b6";
   max-height: 100%;
   width: 29px;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   margin-top: -.1em;
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Damn thats clever

Comment: this is nice trick, but can be improved, only needs `border-top` and no need `display:block`

Comment: @dippas I've append one more variant according to your notes

Comment: @Banzay it worked in FF, don't know which browser are you using

Answer (score 4):

If you have  a lot of `list-items`,then the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633167/3448527) given by @Banzay is cleaner,  but if you just have few of them, you can use `nth-child` for that

```css
li:first-child {
  margin-left: 10px
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 20px
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 30px
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: 40px
}
/*just demo*/

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```