# "Stair-step" sibling elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

Without JavaScript, is it possible to create a flowing stair-step cascade of elements?

Meaning:

```
[1]
   [2]
      [3]
         [.]
```

So on and so forth for any number of elements.

I'm working with the markup something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

By flowing, I mean it doesn't matter how many elements I have in the steps, it will just work - so no absolute positioning per individual elements, or making each one have progressively more margins (unless there's some way to do that perpetually in css I don't know of).

Also, no infinite child elements - an acceptable solution could have more elements mixed in if necessary, but the boxes should not be children of each other.

Fixed sizes are okay, though flexible is preferred.

I do have a [pen going here](https://codepen.io/freer4/pen/MGxMJX), but no success yet.

Comment: No...it's not. Sorry.

Comment: maybe this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633167/4206079 will be helpful

Comment: just because the limitations in the requirements seem a bit strange to me: What are you trying to achieve here? If no absolute positioning or margins, how did you plan to get this gap created? Why no Javascript? (is this an XY problem?)

Comment: @Kaddath you COULD use either of those, but not progressively. Like :nth-child(1) margin 50, 2 has margin 100, etc. Because you would have to write infinite lines of css to cover an infinite possible number of boxes.

Comment: basic idea is to create `:before` element for `div`. Along with `float:left` of div, `:before`' height has to exceed a little bit a height of `div`.... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/derBaX

Comment: @Paulie_D oh ye of little faith, welcome to CSS wizardry. Never give up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Banzay for the link, I worked it out using a child element that floats, and added another layer of containment to the content as an inline-block element.

```css
*{border-width:0;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

#con{
  margin:50px;
  background:#acc;
}
#con>div{
  position:relative;
  background:#ccd;
  height:50px;
}
#con>div:before {
    float: left;
    content: "\00a0";
    width: 50px;
    height: 51px;
}
#con>div>div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
  <div><div>1</div></div>
  <div><div>2</div></div>
  <div><div>3</div></div>  
  <div><div>4</div></div>  
  <div><div>5</div></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: you got it :) I was also playing with float and I didn't find the trick !

Comment: by the way I edited my answer to make it dynamic height width ;)

Comment: @Randy Hall,  you can vote up my hint here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633167/4206079 :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an idea if you can adjust the HTML:

<sup>I know, it rely on nested elements and not siblings one</sup>

```css
.container {
 position:relative;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
}

.container  div{
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid;
  left:100%;
  top:100%;
}

.container  div.bigger {
  width:100px;
}
.container  div.taller {
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>1
      <div class="taller">2
        <div>3
          <div class="bigger">4
            <div>5</div>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                      </div>
                        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant way! I like it.

Comment: Erm... *"the boxes should not be children of each other."*

Comment: @Paulie_D I know :) that's why added a small notice ... by the way it can be dynamic with different height/wdith ;)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is dynamically generated HTML, you could possibly leverage your server-side language to set variables and use them with a `calc` function in your CSS.

```css
div {
 margin-top: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 
 /* This is the important line */
 margin-left: calc(var(--indent) * 15px);
}
```

```html
<div style="--indent: 0;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 1;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 2;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 3;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 4;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 5;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 6;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 7;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 8;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 9;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 10;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 11;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 12;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 13;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 14;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 15;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 16;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 17;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 18;"></div>
<div style="--indent: 19;"></div>
```

Of course if you can do that, it does beg the question why not just use your scripting language to set `margin-left: ${incrementor} * indent` inline.

I did look at trying to leverage a CSS counter, but sadly `calc` does not support using counters yet